# Relation of two definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals

For a differentiable continuous function $g(u)$ over a finite region $R$, I know that
$$\int_R e^u g\; u\; du = 1$$
Is there any way to determine from this the value of
$$\int_R 10^u g\; u\; du$$

Comment: What is $g$ alone.

Comment: We don't have any expression for $g(u)$; only that it's the same in both integrals, as is the range of integration.

Comment: It is possible only if $g(u)$=constant or linear.

Answer (score 0):

The second integral is

$$J=\int 10^u g(u)du =$$

$$=\int e^{uln(10)}g(u)du=.$$

put $v=u ln(10)$

then

$$J=\frac{1}{ln(10)}\int e^v g(\frac{v}{ln(10)})dv.$$

So, in general, we cannot get tha value of $J$

from $I=\int e^u g(u)du=1$.

if $g$ is linear  then $J=\frac{1}{(ln(10))^2}$.

Answer (score -1):

No, it depends on $g$ look at the two cases $g(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: How do I look at these? What is known is the value of the integral. The function g is identical for the two integrals shown; the only difference is $e^u$ vs $10^u$.